# Can't see a widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

I've been trying to create a frame to be shown as a tooltip, but be functionally different. It's got to be shown at a certain point, floating, to be called from a delegate.

Now, if I don't pass a parent it's seen but yeah, it's detached.
And I want it to be windowless.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
  #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QFrame>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSize size { 350, 550 };
    QPoint topLeft { 550, 550 };
    auto* frame = new QFrame(this); // this is a QWidget
    frame->setGeometry({ topLeft, size });
    frame->show();
    frame->activateWindow();
    frame->raise();

    qInfo() << frame->isVisible(); // returns true
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Article amended. Please take a look

Comment: `QMainWindow` is a bit 'special' in that you can't, generally speaking, just add child widgets directly -- they need to be part of the central widget hierachy.

Comment: I checked. You are right. I set it as a central block and it seems to have started working.